# How can i get two objects from array using javascript from specific position?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get two objects from array using the `splice()` method. But it is not working as expected. Please guide me where i am wrong or help me to fix this. if anybody can modify this code to a simpler version would be appreciated.

Basically, I am trying to join two objects `title` and `content`. So please help me to fix this.

```js
const output = [{
"title": "Lorem Ipsum Test Title 1"
},
{
"content": "The short answer to this is yes."
},
{
"title": "Lorem Ipsum Test Title 2"
},
{
"content": "The short answer to this is yes."
},
{
"title": "Lorem Ipsum Test Title 3"
},
{
"content": "The short answer to this is yes."
},
{
"title": "Lorem Ipsum Test Title 4"
},
{
"content": "The short answer to this is yes."
}
];;
let start = 0;
let end = 2;
const finalOutput = [];
for (j = 0; j <= output.length; j++) {
  const data = output.splice(start, end);

  if (typeof data[0] != 'undefined') {
    finalOutput.push({
      title: data[0].title,
      content: data[1].content
    });
  }

  start = start + 2;
  end = end + 2;
}

console.log(finalOutput)
```

The final output from the above code is below. It skips two objects.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you can think about a method with more functional

```js
const output = [{
  "title": "Title 1"
},
{
  "content": "Content 1"
},
{
  "title": "Title 2"
},
{
  "content": "Content 2"
},
{
  "title": "Title 3"
},
{
  "content": "Content 3"
}];
const reducer = (pre, cur) => {
  if (cur.content) {
    pre[pre.length - 1].content = cur.content;
    return pre;
  }
  return [...pre, {
    title: cur.title
  }]
}
const join = output.reduce(reducer, [])

console.log(join) // [{"title":"Title 1","content":"Content 1"},{"title":"Title 2","content":"Content 2"},{"title":"Title 3","content":"Content 3"}]
```

Answer (score 2):

You have an issue in that `output.length` changes during your iteration, and you are splicing from increasing indexes, although because you have spliced the array has shortened. If you want to keep using [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice), change your code as follows:

```js
const output = [{
    "title": "Lorem Ipsum Test Title"
  },
  {
    "content": "The short answer to this is yes."
  },
  {
    "title": "Lorem Ipsum Test Title #2"
  },
  {
    "content": "The short answer to this is also yes."
  },
  {
    "title": "Lorem Ipsum Test Title #3"
  },
  {
    "content": "The short answer to this is not yes."
  }
];
const finalOutput = [];
const len = output.length;
for (j = 0; j < len; j+=2) {
  const data = output.splice(0, 2);
  finalOutput.push({
    title: data[0].title,
    content: data[1].content
  });
}

console.log(finalOutput)
```

Alternatively, use [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) and the code might be more logical:

```js
const output = [{
    "title": "Lorem Ipsum Test Title"
  },
  {
    "content": "The short answer to this is yes."
  },
  {
    "title": "Lorem Ipsum Test Title #2"
  },
  {
    "content": "The short answer to this is also yes."
  },
  {
    "title": "Lorem Ipsum Test Title #3"
  },
  {
    "content": "The short answer to this is not yes."
  }
];
const finalOutput = [];
for (j = 0; j < output.length; j+=2) {
  const data = output.slice(j, j+2);
  finalOutput.push({
    title: data[0].title,
    content: data[1].content
  });
}

console.log(finalOutput)
```

Note in both cases `start` and `end` are redundant and you don't need the check on `data[0]` as it is guaranteed to be valid.

Answer (score 0):

I think Ghost has the best answer - neat and simple.

I had something along those lines but not as neat:

```
output.map((value, index, array) => {
  if (index == 0 || index % 2 == 0){
    const contentIndex = index + 1;    
    return { "title": value.title, "content": array[contentIndex].content }    
  }
}).filter(o => o !== undefined);
```

Answer (score 0):

//easiest way to do is

```
<script>
    let value=[]
    const output = [
        {
            "title": "Lorem Ipsum Test Title"
        },
        {
            "content": "The short answer to this is yes."
        },
        {
            "title": "Lorem Ipsum Test Title"
        },
        {
            "content": "The short answer to this is yes."
        },
        {
            "title": "Lorem Ipsum Test Title"
        },
        {
            "content": "The short answer to this is yes."
        }
    ];
    for(let i=0;i<output.length;){
        value.push({...output[i],...output[i+1]})
        i+=2;
    }
    console.log(value)

</script>
```